# Python Multiprocessing doesn't seem to end

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a process which moves lots of data into a database. I use multiprocessing for this.

It runs nice and quickly, but even when it's finished (all the rows are moved), it doesn't seem to end.

I've added join as I thought it means that the process won't terminate until all other processes are complete

Is there something I have missed here? why doesn't it end?

```
p=mp.Pool(cpu_count())
p.map(do_process, result)
p.close()
p.join()
```

Comment: I've noticed that `multiprocessing` tends to swallow exceptions without reporting them. Try wrapping the body of `do_process` in a `try`/`except` block and printing any exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a nicer way of doing it, it to use joblib:

```
import joblib

with joblib.parallel_backend('loky'):
    results = joblib.Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(
        joblib.delayed(do_process)(item) 
        for item in result
        )
```

I am assuming here that that the `result` object is mapped over the `do_process` function. The `with` statement ensure closing the loop. If you want to know of what is happening, then you can add a verbosity setting to the `joblib.Parralel` object.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot - what does 'loky' mean here/

Comment: `loky` is the backend. It is the default backend to spawn more processes and run stuff in parallel. There are backends like dask, that support cluster computers and various GPU accelerated backend. The TL;DR is, `loky` is default, and probably the fastest on a local machine :)